# Jhipster public api encounter Unauthorized status 401

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

My Project needs to set up a callback API to receive a biometric punchlog. I exposed a public API [.antMatchers("/api/daily-time-records").permitAll()] but I encounter error when I test it in postman

"type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
"title": "Unauthorized",
"status": 401,
"detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
"path": "/api/daily-time-records%0A",
"message": "error.http.401"

Resource

```
 @PostMapping("/daily-time-records")
public ResponseEntity<DailyTimeRecordDTO> createDailyTimeRecord(@Valid @RequestBody DailyTimeRecordDTO dailyTimeRecordDTO)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to save DailyTimeRecord : {}", dailyTimeRecordDTO);
    if (dailyTimeRecordDTO.getId() != null) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new dailyTimeRecord cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
    }
    DailyTimeRecordDTO result = dailyTimeRecordService.save(dailyTimeRecordDTO);
    return ResponseEntity
        .created(new URI("/api/daily-time-records/" + result.getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}
```

Security Configuration

```
 @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
    .and()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
    .and()
        .permissionsPolicy().policy("camera=(), fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), sync-xhr=()")
    .and()
        .frameOptions()
        .deny()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/daily-time-records").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .and()
        .httpBasic()
    .and()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm me that you have something like that @RequestMapping(value = "/api") on the top of your controller class ?

Comment: The error mentions `/api/biometric-punch-log` not `/api/daily-time-records` that you allowed for all in security configuration.

Comment: @sixrandanes Yes

Comment: @GaëlMarziou it is my mistake because I try so many resources.    Below is the latest try.                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                             
  {
    "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/api/daily-time-records%0A",
    "message": "error.http.401"
}